# Alert in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

i want to add alert while buy / sell signal generated.
Below is my pinescript.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='TEST08032023', overlay=true)

s9ema = ta.ema(close, 9)
s18ema = ta.ema(close, 18)

longCond = ta.crossover(s9ema, s18ema)
shortCond = ta.crossunder(s9ema, s18ema)

plotshape(series=longCond, title='BUY', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), text='BUY', size=size.small)
plotshape(series=shortCond, title='SELL', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), text='SELL', size=size.small)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it -- below your code, put:

```
alertcondition(condition=longCond, title="Buy Signal", message="Buy Signal")
alertcondition(condition=shortCond, title="Sell Signal", message="Sell Signal")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This has two solutions on PinescriptV5, using the `alert` or `alertcondition` function.

By using `alertcondition`, you can choose which alert you want to enable. For example, you can enable long alerts only rather than enable all of them. if using the `alert` function, you will make all `alert` functions when activated. This can benefit you if you don't want to have multiple alerts when using a script. More info, you can check images below.

This is the updated version of your code:

1. Using `alertcondition` function

   ````
   indicator(title='TEST08032023', overlay=true)

   s9ema = ta.ema(close, 9)
   s18ema = ta.ema(close, 18)

   longCond = ta.crossover(s9ema, s18ema)
   shortCond = ta.crossunder(s9ema, s18ema)

   alertcondition(longCond, title = "Long Alert", message = "Long")
   alertcondition(shortCond, title = "Short Alert", message = "Short")

   plotshape(series=longCond, title='BUY', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), text='BUY', size=size.small)
   plotshape(series=shortCond, title='SELL', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), text='SELL', size=size.small)```
   ````
2. Using `alert` function

   ````
   indicator(title='TEST08032023', overlay=true)

   s9ema = ta.ema(close, 9)
   s18ema = ta.ema(close, 18)

   longCond = ta.crossover(s9ema, s18ema)
   shortCond = ta.crossunder(s9ema, s18ema)

   if longCond
       alert("Long")
   if shortCond
       alert("Short")

   plotshape(series=longCond, title='BUY', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), text='BUY', size=size.small)
   plotshape(series=shortCond, title='SELL', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), text='SELL', size=size.small)```
   ````

After adding it to the code, don't forget to activate it as image below. Hope this helps.

1. Click "Add alert ..." on the indicator's "more" option.
2. Select "Any alert() function" if you using `alert`, "Long Alert" or "Short Alert" if you using `alertcondition` (options may differ depending on how you write `alertcondition` on your code).
3. Click "Create" button.
4. Check Alert panel if it already active.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
if longCond
    alert('BUY SIGNAL', alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
if shortCond
    alert('SHORT SIGNAL', alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```